# How to access a procedure created in another schema?

Tags: oracle

I have a procedure in a schema. I want to access it and execute by logging in as another user. For that I gave execute permission as grant execute on `<procedure>` to public. But when I tried to execute in another schema, its showing error and I am not able to execute. What to do? Is there any other permissions to be granted?

Comment: did you call it with the schema_name.procedure_name? You need to do this if you don't have a synonym set up for it.

Comment: You need share more details about errors. It might not be complaining about executing the stored procedure on which you have granted permissions. It might be complaining on other stored procedures invoked or other objects accessed.

Comment: Also, if you set it up with invoker rights (authid current_user), then the logged in user will also need permissions on objects that the procedure is accessing.